# Copied and pasted code C# from a ASMR Youtube Video however it’s not working for me?

Tags: c#

I’m new to coding and has been doing a Junior Software Development Bootcamp for less than a month. Currently, we are learning software fundamentals and C#.

To get in the groove of things and ease into it (as stress-free as possible) I decided to watch an [ASMR video on Explaining Object-Oriented Programming with C#](https://youtu.be/uqyZmimgMQs) and follow along by copying the code into my Visual Studio program.

So here is the problem, I followed along exactly what the developer was typing in the video, however on my Visual Studio program  I seem to be getting 2 red squiggly lines on 2 parts of the code I copied.

If someone could help me out here as to why the code is not working, I would be grateful.

This is the whole code

```cs
using System;

namespace ExplainingOOP
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var checkingAccount = new Account();
            
        }

        public class Account {
            private const double MAX_ALLOWED_Limit = 100000;
            public string AccountOwnerName { get; set; }
            private double _balance;
            public double Balance { get { return _balance; } }


            public void DepositMoney(double amount) { 
              CheckIfDepositedAmountLooksOkay(amount);
                _balance += amount;
            }

            public void WithdrawMoney(double amount) {
                CheckIfBalanceLooksRight(amount);
                _balance -= amount;
            }

            private void CheckIfBalanceLooksRight(double amount) { {
                    if (_balance == 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Insufficient balance");
                    }
                    if (_balance < amount)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("You are trying to withdraw money more than your balance. Please lower your balance.");
                    }
                    if (Balance < 0)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("There is something seriously wrong here. Contact the bank teller.");
                    }
                }
                if (amount > MAX_ALLOWED_Limit) {
                    throw new Exception("You cannot depost more than what's allowed daily. Please contact your bank agent for more infomation.");
                }
                if (amount <= 0) {
                    throw new Exception("This does not look right. You may not deposit 0 or less amount of money to your account. The eroor is being reported to the bank. Thanks for your patience");
                }
            }
        }


        private void CheckIfDepostiedAmountLooksOkay(double amount) {
            if (amount > MAX_ALLOWED_LIMIT) {
                throw new Exception("You cannot deposit more than what's allowed daily. Please contact your bank agent for more infomation");
            }
            if (amount <= 0) {
                throw new Exception("this does not look right. You may deposit 0 or less amount of money to your account. The error is being reported to your bank. Thanks for your patience.");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this error message i'm getting

```cs
/Users/shahzadh/Documents/Software Developer Bootcamp /Projects/ASMR Developer/Explaining Object Oriented Programming with C#/ExplainingOOP/ExplainingOOP/Program.cs(17,17): Error CS0103: The name 'CheckIfDepositedAmountLooksOkay' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (ExplainingOOP)
/Users/shahzadh/Documents/Software Developer Bootcamp /Projects/ASMR Developer/Explaining Object Oriented Programming with C#/ExplainingOOP/ExplainingOOP/Program.cs(26,26): Error CS0103: The name 'MAX_ALLOWED_LIMIT' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (ExplainingOOP)
```

Comment: "I seem to be getting 2 red squiggly lines" that's a funny description. Move the function `CheckIfDepostiedAmountLooksOkay` into the class Account.

Comment: Software development is often an exercise in precision.  The tutorial with sock puppets makes this a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

1. you have a typo into CheckIfDepos**ti**edAmountLooksOkay, so compiler was unable to find method;
2. You have a wrong case into `MAX_ALLOWED_Limit`. C# is case-sensitive;
3. You set curly braces wrong before method `CheckIfDepostiedAmountLooksOkay`, so this method was outside of the class `Account`.

The right code would be:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var checkingAccount = new Account();
    }

    public class Account
    {
        private const double MAX_ALLOWED_LIMIT = 100000;
        public string AccountOwnerName { get; set; }
        private double _balance;

        public double Balance
        {
            get { return _balance; }
        }


        public void DepositMoney(double amount)
        {
            CheckIfDepositedAmountLooksOkay(amount);
            _balance += amount;
        }

        public void WithdrawMoney(double amount)
        {
            CheckIfBalanceLooksRight(amount);
            _balance -= amount;
        }

        private void CheckIfBalanceLooksRight(double amount)
        {
            {
                if (_balance == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Insufficient balance");
                }

                if (_balance < amount)
                {
                    throw new Exception(
                        "You are trying to withdraw money more than your balance. Please lower your balance.");
                }

                if (Balance < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("There is something seriously wrong here. Contact the bank teller.");
                }
            }
            if (amount > MAX_ALLOWED_LIMIT)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "You cannot depost more than what's allowed daily. Please contact your bank agent for more infomation.");
            }

            if (amount <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "This does not look right. You may not deposit 0 or less amount of money to your account. The eroor is being reported to the bank. Thanks for your patience");
            }
        }


        private void CheckIfDepositedAmountLooksOkay(double amount)
        {
            if (amount > MAX_ALLOWED_LIMIT)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "You cannot deposit more than what's allowed daily. Please contact your bank agent for more infomation");
            }

            if (amount <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "this does not look right. You may deposit 0 or less amount of money to your account. The error is being reported to your bank. Thanks for your patience.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, 

Thank you so much for that! However it seems to have bought up a new issue with 'Exception' could not be found  ```c# /Users/shahzadh/Documents/Software Developer Bootcamp /Projects/ASMR Developer/Explaining Object Oriented Programming with C#/ExplainingOOP/ExplainingOOP/Program.cs(31,31): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Exception' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (ExplainingOOP)```

Comment: @z52782 did you put `using System;` at the top of the file?

Comment: I managed to fix it, Thanks